# Get key/value from selected Autocomplete item

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using this jquery plugin.

I've looked at the documentation but I'm still not sure how to get the key value from the selected item.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: I've seen the source at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete I don't think you need to get keys or values for simple working. Plugin takes care of itself. If you have special requirements please elaborate and post code which you are trying.

Comment: There is something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561365/value-is-applied-instead-of-label-to-textbox#autocomment12205408

Answer (score 0):

You should have some kind of callback function, like this one (those functions are from demo):

```
function findValueCallback(event, data, formatted) {
    $("<li>").html( !data ? "No match!" : "Selected: " + formatted).appendTo("#result");
}
```

And then you should add this function as a handler for "result" event on your textboxes:

```
$(":text, textarea").result(findValueCallback).next().click(function() {
    $(this).prev().search();
});
```

Comment: ok. Doesn't that mean I will have to make a call back to the database to find out the key?